# Drupal sub directory url

Tags: uri

I just started using Drupal today and I couldn't help but notice (or I'm blind) there is no way to add a sub directory style URL besides using an alias. I want to have a category, for example, named "lessons" and then the next part of the URL would be the title of the lesson.

e.g. http://www.example.com/lessons/lesson1

It just seems like there should be a better way to accomplish this rather than using aliases manually. So my question is, is there a way to do this without aliases? I mean automatically so when I add new content (an Article), I can select the appropriate category it should be in. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

http://drupal.org/project/pathauto

this module do what you want ... this module generate url automatically depending on the node title... and you can add prefix or suffix to the automatic url path that generated by this module

if you are using drupal 6 then you can configure this module from

http://yoursite.com/admin/build/path/pathauto